# One word for "bringing someone up to speed"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm trying to explain the following thought:

> She has been tremendously helpful in training new employees in the company...

only instead of "training", I would like to use a word that emphasizes the fact that employees "know what to do" after she's done with them :) Like "bringing up to speed" but with one word.

Comment: If they don't know what to do when she's done with them, they've hardly been trained.

Comment: @cornbreadninja I thought that training only implies the process, not necessarily "graduation" :)

Comment: @cornbreadninja is right. It sounds like you have a very dim view of training.

Comment: "... in making new employees efficient ..." ?

Comment: I'll cover my eyes while I suggest business jargon, "effectivizing". The reception for that depends on your audience, but certainly some might think it's a linguistic masterstroke.

Comment: @JEL, "operationalizing new staff" is perhaps more acceptable for a larger audience.

Comment: Ironically, I would think that the word "training" has even more of a "they know what to do" emphasis than "bringing up to speed" does. As cornbread says, if you don't know what to do, you haven't been properly trained.

Comment: Just use training.

Comment: As God is my witness, do not use *'onboarding'*. That's mutilating the language.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: sadly 'training' doesn't have the connotations of 'telling someone everything they need to be productive, and fit in': part training, part tips and tricks, part political primer. There really is no one word.

Comment: @smci I agree with you that onboarding is hideous (well, my feelings about that word...maybe too strong for you).  How does training not have that connotation?

Comment: @smci I've been to many job training sessions where they give me tips and tricks and ideas for how to get along with others.  I usually don't advocate expanding one's definition of a word, but in this case, I think it's fine to do that.

Comment: (you can have my cliches, after you pry them from my cold, dead hands): *She has been tremendously helpful bringing the new employees up to speed.*

Comment: Eschew bafflegab, "Onboarding" is awful corporate lingo, stick with plain english.

Comment: "enlighten" is the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: oddly, the word that nearly literally means "bringing up to speed" - accelerating - does not apply here.

Comment: @LorenaDerežanin to "fast track" is the the best term in the context of your example. Fast-tracking is to "accelerate the development or progress of (a person or project)" and is often used to describe accelerated training programs in companies

Answer (score 45):

**Onboarding**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onboarding) defines this as

> The mechanism through which new employees acquire the necessary
>   knowledge, skills, and behaviors to become effective organizational
>   members and insiders.

*"She has been tremendously helpful onboarding the company's new employees."*

In my experience this term is very common in the HR field and is often used during the new hire process. My view of onboarding includes any type of activity or process that is aimed at preparing a new employee for his/her position. It can include training, getting certifications, briefing on policies and so on. I assume the process varies widely depending on the position and field of work.

Comment: This is even less valuable and more a buzzword than "training" ever was.

Comment: Please attribute sources; I've done this here.

Comment: First reaction: That is a horrible word.

Comment: Verbing weirds language

Comment: I had a feeling that the hardcore grammarians would shudder at this suggestion. However in my experience it is very common in the HR field and is often used during the new hire process. I also think it meets the needs of the OP quite well regardless of its buzzy weirdness.

Comment: Agree that it has a buzz factor, but we use it in my company too (tech company).  If you don't like this, stick with _training_.

Comment: In my experience, "onboarding' is usually associated with teaching new hires about policies and procedures rather than how to do the job. At the end of it, you may know how to fill out your timesheet, meet the compliance requirements, and pick up your new laptop, but still suck at your job.

Comment: @LaconicDroid interesting in my experience (software companies) it has been quite involved and can include several weeks of courses, getting certifications etc. I assume it varies widely depending on the position and field of work.

Comment: @Chris R - to me, that would be training, not "onboarding".

Comment: I think this word is acceptable (besides "training", the most acceptable answer given).  If you're concerned with the depth of knowledge / skill gain incurred during "onboarding", perhaps you'd prefer "ramping up", which has the additional connotation that the workers might be technically adept in the first place, but was brought "up to speed" on the very specifics of the job as they pertain to this particular scenario.

Comment: @LaconicDroid I guess my view of onboarding includes any type of activity or process that is aimed at preparing the new employee for the position. So it can include training, briefing on policies and so on.

Comment: What an ugly word (-1 for even thinking of it and a protest against anyone using it). It puts me in mind of a torture technique used in Guantanamo Bay.  A word such as this shouldn't be allowed to degrade the beautiful English language.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK How dare I even think of it!!! ;)

Comment: Please do not merely cite dictionary senses: ELU is not Google. Please provide your own supporting arguments, in entirely your own words, for why you believe this is an appropriate answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Robusto True, but perhaps we should be grateful people don't say "upspeeding".

Comment: This is horrible. Please, let's all agree to forget that this word ever existed.

Answer (score 34):

*Briefing* is a good one.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/briefing?s=t

> 2.
>   any set of concise instructions or a summary of events.

However, it may be too authoritative for your purposes.

Answer (score 18):

**Inducting**

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induct):

> **induct**: Admit (someone) formally to a post or organization

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_programme):

> An induction programme is part of an organisations knowledge management process and is intended to enable the new starter to become a useful, integrated member of the team, rather than being "thrown in at the deep end" without understanding how to do their job, or how their role fits in with the rest of the company.

Comment: Sometimes I think people would rather create a new word such as the awful "onboarding" when a more than adequate word exists but they cannot be bothered to find it, such as "induct". Lazy!

Comment: Please do not merely cite dictionary senses: ELU is not Google. Please provide your own supporting arguments, in entirely your own words, for why you believe this is an appropriate answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 16):

**acclimate**: to accustom or become accustomed to a new climate or environment; adapt.([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acclimate))

The difference between "accustomed" and "acclimated" is that "accustomed" is familiar through use; usual; customary while "acclimated" is accustomed, adapted, or hardened to some environment. ([the-difference-between.com](http://the-difference-between.com/acclimated/accustomed))

*She has been tremendously helpful in getting the company's new employees acclimated.*

Comment: +1. Good word. One additional comment, however. The word "acclimated," if I'm not mistaken, would be more appropriate if the trainer's job is to familiarize the newbie to the company's culture, so to speak--you know, the company's policies, procedures, and "how we do things around here." I could be wrong, but to acclimate someone is not necessarily to bring someone to the point where s/he knows what to do and how to do it, as in the nitty gritty aspects of the job description. Minor point, however. Don

Comment: So what about just using the word "accustom"?

Comment: @PierreArlaud Hope this helps: http://the-difference-between.com/acclimated/accustomed

Comment: @Elian this would possibly be a nice addition to the answer :)

Answer (score 10):

> apprising
>
> ap·prise
>   əˈprīz/
>   verb
>   gerund or present participle: apprising
>
> inform or tell (someone). 
>   "I thought it right to apprise Chris of what had happened" 
>   synonyms:  inform, tell, notify, advise, brief, make aware, enlighten, update, keep posted

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you please give a citation to the dictionary you were using?

Comment: Please do not merely cite dictionary senses: ELU is not Google. Please provide your own supporting arguments, in entirely your own words, for why you believe this is an appropriate answer to the question asked.

Comment: "Which dictionary?"  "Hey, no dictionaries" LOL!  "Get out! And don't come back!"

Answer (score 8):

How about [***familiarizing***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/familiarize)?  To *familiarize* somebody with something means to make them familiar with it.

> She has been tremendously helpful in familiarizing new employees with the company's procedures.

Answer (score 5):

Although I would totally understand your desire to find a better word than “orienting” [new employees **to** the company] to capture “bringing [them] up to speed,” I’m not sure what’s wrong with “training.”  Once oriented, employees, both veterans and rookies need to be [trained](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/train?s=t) and [updated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/update?s=t) to bring them up [back] (in the case of veterans) to speed.

> To train/verb: Def 19: to make proficient by instruction and practice,
>   as in some art, profession, or work:
>
> To update/verb: Def 3: to bring (a person, organization, etc.) up to
>   date on a particular subject:

(both from Dictionary[dot]com)

Answer (score 2):

**orienting**

From the definition of **orient** at [Dictionary.com:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/orienting)

> 5. to familiarize (a person) with new surroundings or circumstances, or the like:
>      *lectures designed to orient the new students.*

When there is a formal procedure for orienting new employees to a company, it is sometimes called "new employee orientation".

Answer (score 1):

A perfect word for the phenomenon of which you are speaking, at least in matters of religion, is *discipling*.  The goal of Christian discipleship, for example, is for the more-mature disciple to "reproduce" him- or herself in the life of the person who is being discipled. That person in turn disciples another Christian who is less mature than he or she, and so on.

I don't think, however, you'll get away with "She has been tremendously helpful in discipling new employees." Perhaps the word *mentoring* would be useful, in that it denotes the efforts of a more-experienced employee in bringing a less-experienced employee up to speed through teaching, exemplifying, encouraging, instructing step-by-step, and more.

A more prosaic word, of course, is *teaching* (or *instructing*). Mentoring, however, has a nice ring to it.

Comment: `discipling` barely resembles `bringing someone up to speed`.   `discipling` is an ongoing process, much like `mentoring`.   `briefing`, or `bringing up to speed` is a short term thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively new word *onboarding* that you might be interested in. It does not fit the bill exactly, as it is from employee’s perspective instead of the trainer’s.

*Mentoring* is another "power packed" word, and it might fit well here.

Comment: Ah.I see onboarding has already gathered steam .. Yeah I did not see that as I was writing.

Comment: (-1 for supporting such an ugly word).

Answer (score 0):

**priming**

A person would read a primer to get brought up to speed in a subject, so I think a reasonable word choice is *priming*.

From dict.org:

> ```
>  3. To prepare; to make ready; to instruct beforehand; to
>     post; to coach; as, to prime a witness; the boys are
>     primed for mischief. [Colloq.] --Thackeray.
>     [1913 Webster]
> ```

Comment: Please do not merely cite dictionary senses: ELU is not Google. Please provide your own supporting arguments, in entirely your own words, for why you believe this is an appropriate answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

A word that took on broader meanings with the Information Age, **inform** originally meant exactly what you're looking for:  to train in technical matters.

Answer (score 0):

Break in ; teach the ropes; clue in; fill in;
Examples: she's been instrumental in breaking in the new employees.